# Rearrange Priority Queue so that there is no gap in between

Tags: python, priority-queue

The result of the following code I wrote is not something I want but I was unsure how to change it. My data are saved in a list of dictionaries

```
        def rearrange_priority(self):
        current_highest_priority = self.get_highest_priority()
        new_priority = current_highest_priority + 1
        used_priorities = set()

        for task in self.queue:
            if task['Priority'] == current_highest_priority:
                # if this customer has the current highest priority, keep the same priority number
                pass
            else:
                # if this customer has a lower priority number, update their priority to the new priority
                if task['Priority'] in used_priorities:
                    # if another customer already has the same priority number, don't increment new_priority
                    pass
                else:
                    task['Priority'] = new_priority
                    new_priority += 1
                    used_priorities.add(task['Priority'])
```

I was trying to rearrange the priority in a queue so that there is no gap in between. (Assume 0 is the highest priority)

Example Priority of Original Queue: 0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 5

Example of Results I want to achieve: 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3

but using this code, the result will be 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Is there any new approach to done this question ? Thanks a lot

Comment: “I was trying to rearrange the priority in a queue so that there is no gap in between.” Why? You shouldn’t be poking around in the interior of any container objects, as you’ll very likely break them. Bear in mind that priority queues are dynamic, so manually altering priorities at some point in time will probably make the results inconsistent with future entries.

Comment: @pjs I've try it with another code but it still doesn't work, is there any idea? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Priorities only need to be compared to other priorities, so as long as the priorities are in the right order then it doesn't matter what their actual values are. If you want to enumerate the distinct priorities later then you can do that where the values from the queue are consumed. But this also assumes you will insert everything into the queue before anything is consumed (if not, then there is no way to know the correct enumeration), in which case you can just sort, there is no need for a priority queue at all.

Comment: @janiceeeee I'm purposefully not making suggestions for how to do this because I'm trying to tell you it's probably not a good idea. Perhaps you can offer some compelling justification?

Comment: Its something requested by the question, I'm just completing it to fulfill the question's requirement

Comment: @janiceeeee Requested by what question? Are you saying this is a homework? If so, then I'm definitely out of here. I'm a professor, and firmly believe that the value of homework is in the doing of the homework, not in watching how other people do it. You don't learn to play a musical instrument just by watching somebody else do it, you have to get hands-on.